# Do I still need an ipv4 address? Can I just use an ipv6?

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6, ip-address, ipv4

**I am unsure if this should be on SuperUser or ServerFault. Please migrate it instead of closing it if you think it's offtopic.**

A few months ago, Vultr got a cheaper plan that only includes an ipv6 address, not an ipv4 one. I was wondering if this would be okay to use for client-facing applications (eg. a webserver), as I assume most ISPs now have support for IPv6? I am aware that people with only IPv4 won't be able to connect, but is that a real problem? After all, ICANN ran out of IPv4 addresses just under 8 years ago.

Comment: We've already answered this on [sf]. See [Should I use IPv6 only or both IPv4 and IPv6 in my web server?](https://serverfault.com/q/421445/126632)

Comment: *"I am aware that people with only IPv4 won't be able to connect, but is that a real problem?"* -- Yes, this is still a significant issue if you are offering this service to the public.

Comment: What I'm saying, is do enough people have IPv6 addresses that this wouldn't be too much of a problem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton How would I know that? English Language doesn't tell me if my question's on Philosophy.

Comment: Anyway, that's if you have both (which in my opinion was a stupid question).

Comment: You wouldn't be expected to know it. That's why I gave you the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that ICANN ran out of IPv4 addresses affects only the impossibility of issuing new addresses, but does not mean that millions of users of IPv4 addresses received earlier have suddenly ceased (or will cease in the near future) to use them. Therefore, you can only opt out of IPv4 support if you are absolutely sure that all users of your services have switched to IPv6 (or if your services simply do not need users ;)

Comment: But clients can have both, so what I'm asking is do enough people now have IPv6 that I don't need to worry about IPv4?

Comment: @ArchieBaer, according to Google stats only about 25% of users use IPv6 today: https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html

Comment: Okay, so not a good idea. I'll spend the extra 50p.